# Sharepoint 2010 advanced sort

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using advanced sort for a date view web part to set up a 3 part hierarchy. One of the fields is @Meeting_x0020_Name. The @ sign returns all attributes for the context node, which gives me something like  3;#2014 2nd Quarter Meeting.

I don't want to display 3;# but only meeting name. How would I do that?
I'm not using code, but only the built in functions in SP.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
substring-after(@Meeting_x0020_Name,'#')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is going to be possible with out-of-the-box web parts in SharePoint 2010.  Sorting is a bit limited already in 2010 an there is nothing built into the out-of-the-box web parts to allow you to parse out the meeting name.  You may need to consider a custom solution if this is a requirement.